# How to draw a straight line in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

How to draw a straight line on imageview in Xamarin using c#. I have to draw the straight line and calculate length of that line.
Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend UIImageView and inside a method draw a line like so:

```
public void DrawLine()
{
    CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
    context.SetLineWidth (4);
    UIColor.Clear.SetFill ();
    UIColor.Black.SetStroke ();
    currentPath = new CGPath ();
    currentPath.AddLines (points.ToArray());
    context.AddPath (currentPath);    
    context.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);   
    context.SaveState ();
}
```

points is a List of PointF objects.